# Change upload size for one specific PHP script only

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm aware of the upload size settings in php.ini, but that's not what I'm asking for. My situation: in my php.ini a reasonable upload size of about 10M is defined which is used globally and for all PHP scripts and which I want to left unchanged for the whole system.

Now I have exactly one PHP script where I would like to allow a much larger upload size. My question: how can I do that without changing the maximum upload size for the whole system? Means is there a way to modify this for just one single script and to leave the size untouched for all other ones?

Thanks!

Comment: `upload_max_filesize` has changeable mode `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, which means you can change it in .htaccess, or with a custom .user.ini. If PHP is running in your Apache as a module, so that it can be configured via .htaccess, you could probably wrap this into a `<Files>` directive to limit the scope; with a custom ini file, you would probably have to move your script to its own directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can this line at the top of your php file.

```
ini_set(upload_max_filesize, "4000M");
```

Comment: That won’t work. PHP will not even _start_ executing your target script, if the file upload  gets discarded due to an upload size violation - so you _can not_ set this from within the script itself, it must be done via “outside” configuration, so that a sufficiently large value is _already_ set, before the script gets called.